# Docker compose/ failed to create task for container

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

when i up my docker (docker-compose up --build) i take this error:

```
shop-backend-database     | 2024-03-01 08:31:53.031 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied
: unknown
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip wheel
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libwebp-dev g++ gcc gettext 
RUN apt install gettext -y
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I did a view set with data processing in excel format, but I don’t think that’s the reason

Comment: BTW: Just search for the error online: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=failed+to+create+task+for+container%3A+failed+to+create+shim+task%3A+OCI+runtime+create+failed%3A+runc+create+failed%3A+unable+to+start+container+process%3A+exec+permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

You have to add execution permission for `entrypoint.sh` file, as the error message says, you don't have permission to execute that file inside the Docker:

> exec: "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied

Like this:

```
...
...
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: I fix it just change Line Separator from CRLF to LF